# exposing C++/CLI classes from dll

Tags: dll, command-line-interface, unmanaged, managed

If i have a C++/CLL dll and I want to expose the C++/CLI classess in the dll such that it can be consumed by non cli applications.  What's the correct syntax so that non-cli projects can see the C++/CLI classes from the dll?

Comment: Declare the type `public`.  That's too obvious, you are doing something else wrong.  We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the reply.  My problem is with non-cli applications.  If i switch the /clr on, it can see the C++/CLI classes.  If its off, then compiler errors would show that even the namespace that covers the class can't be seen.  Yes you're right I am doing it wrong, so if you're experienced with interoperating unmanaged C++ projects with C++/CLI projects, maybe you can suggest it like if the correct appraoch is wrapping it in gcroot or etc.  Im still reading how gcroot works so I can't discuss further.  Maybe later after playing around it.